# Azure SQL Service Management REST API DAPAC Webservice for West Central US datacenter

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm attempting to use the Azure SQL Service Management REST API to Export Database. Unfortunately the above documentation does not list any of the West Central US Region servers. Does anyone know if what the uri Base values are or if they are even supported in the West Central US region?

Comment: microsoft should really publish this

Comment: You can just use sqlpackage.exe with a connection string